# Android application is not copied to the device memory under Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation

I coded an Android application under eclipse
I run this application
The emulators starts and show the Android desktop
But my application is not shown/added on it.
Neither the main activity is started.
What to do ?

Comment: what do the eclipse logs say?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings>>Applications>>Manage Applications` then click on the `All` tab and here you can find the list of the applications installed on your **device or emulator**. So just ensure it wheather your application is installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner too and so far I only manage to test the samples that are packaged with the platform. I had the same problem but when I change the emulator platform and API level everything is working.
Maybe you try to make few different emulators and test run your app on different emulator